# Grid view Dropdown list data binding error

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding, gridview

Am using the below code to bind the dropdown data from another table. And also refer that control name using rowindex. But it always return null.And also return the error message.

```
  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
```

Am using the two method, but both return the control name null

First code:

```
 protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Control ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("DDL_STATUS_FT"); //It always return null
            if (ctrl != null)
            {
                DropDownList dd = ctrl as DropDownList;
                DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter TA = new DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter();
                DataSet7.sp_getall_trv_masterDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
                dd.DataTextField = "fld_TName";
                dd.DataValueField = "fld_id";
                dd.DataSource = DS;
                dd.DataBind();
            }

        }

    }
```

Second :

```
 In databind function



if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView2.DataSource = DS;
        GridView2.DataBind();

    foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter TA1 = new DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter();
        DataSet7.sp_getall_trv_masterDataTable DS1 = TA1.GetData();
        // Nested DropDownList Control reference is passed to the DrdList object. This will allow you access the properties of dropdownlist placed inside the GridView Template column.  
        DropDownList drdList = (DropDownList)(GridView2.Rows[grdRow.RowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DDL_STATUS_FT"));//It always return null

        // DataBinding of nested DropDownList Control for each row of GridView Control.  
        drdList.DataSource = DS1;
        drdList.DataValueField = "fld_id";
        drdList.DataTextField = "fld_TName";
        drdList.DataBind();
    } 
}
```

Please help me to do this..

```
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="TYPE">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_STATUS" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false" >
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_edit_STATUS" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("fld_Type") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_STATUS_FT" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: where is your drop downlist in aspx code `DDL_STATUS_FT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DropDown "DDL_STATUS_FT" is in `Footer Template`..You must check it as follow..

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
  DropDownList ctrl =(DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[CellIndex].FindControl("DDL_STATUS_FT"); 
}
```

Comment: It's working fine..But i have one doubt i want to add this in itemtemplate also

Comment: DataControlRowType.DataRow is used to get Controls in ItemTemplate..You cannot find "DDL_STATUS_FT" if you are checking RowType as Datarow...

Comment: yes i find the items for all row. But i want to include the gridview row edit event.. protected void EditGrade(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData1();
    }  //Error in Bind datasection.

Comment: `private void BindData1()
    {
        DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_config_masterTableAdapter TA = new DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_config_masterTableAdapter();
        DataSet7.sp_getall_trv_config_masterDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
        if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = DS;
            GridView2.DataBind();


        }}`

Comment: @romi...this question was regarding object reference error..and i think it has been solved now...if you have any further issues or queries you can ask them creating new Questions.Formatting is not applied in comment area..so it is difficult to understand what u need.and also if you create new questions chances that u will get perfect solutions will be higher as everyone will be able to see it and help you out...

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED2**

you must have `dropdownlist` in aspx code in gridview item-template

you are finding using `e.row.findcontrol` without declaring it so abusively it return null

so, fist add dropdownlist into your gridview 
here is a sample of your dropdownlist

```
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="DDL_STATUS_FT">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Dropdownlist ID="DDL_STATUS_FT" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

if you got null `ctrl`
Control ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("DDL_STATUS_FT"); //It always return null

then make sure in your aspx code  `DDL_STATUS_FT` Control is `runat="server"`

Comment: DS not dataset, It's a datatable

Comment: if (ctrl != null) value always return null value

Comment: But My dropdown id is present in the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Try to find your control by cell and cellIndex like...

```
Control ctrl = e.Row.Cells[yourCellIndex].FindControl("DDL_STATUS_FT");
```